# Two-step watermark applying using imagemagick

Tags: imagemagick

I am trying to apply watermark to an image of any size using two steps in one command line:

1. Tile small png image and overlay it over the target image.
2. Overlay a logo at top left corner without tiling.

I don't understand the imagemagick command line principles and can't create a command line to make these operations without creatig temporary file between steps 1 and 2. But I am sure this is possible :)

Please help me to do that.
Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, but I need to use imagemagick, not PHP functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve this, but the simplest would be to leverage [ImageMagick's Stack](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php#stack) notation *"`()`"*.

Simply group the first step into a command wrapped in parentheses, and omit the output filename.

```
convert \(                            \
          wizard:                     \
          -size 480x640               \
          -background transparent     \
          tile:label.png -composite   \
        \)                            \
        -gravity NorthEast rose:      \
        -composite output.png
```

The above will compose the `label.png` as a repeating image over the `wizard:` image. *Note, in this example I provided the `-size` and `-background` attributes.* The result of the Image Stack will be accepted as the input image for the second `-composite` operation; which, places the `rose:` image in the top right.

[image: Two-step watermark applying using imagemagick]